# How to create a custom annotation in map in iphone?

Tags: ios4

I m using map in my application. How to create a custom annotation in iphone?
plz give the link to the source...

Comment: Read [Location Awareness Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1) and the sample apps KMLViewer, MapCallouts, and WeatherMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in viewForAnnotation function

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=nil;

    if(annotation!=mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID=@"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView=(MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        if(pinView==nil) 
            pinView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];

        pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;    
        pinView.canShowCallout=YES;

        // to add button to annotation
        UIButton *infobutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        // add ibaction to the button added
        [infobutton addTarget:self action:@selector(showdet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=infobutton;
        pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        [defaultPinID release];
    }
}
```